# How to split a column with scala based on one character and a space

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to pull apart a column "_time" that contains a datetime (as fieldtype = string)

the dates inside the "_time" column look like this: 27-11-2017 08:20:33
So I thought this could work:

```
    df.withColumn("col1", split(col("_time"), "\\-").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("col2", split(col("_time"), "\\-").getItem(1))
  .withColumn("col3", split(col("_time"), "\\-").getItem(2))
  .withColumn("col4", split(col("_time"), "\\' '").getItem(3))
  .show()
```

but this results in:

```
-------------------+----+----+-------------+----+
              _time|col1|col2|         col3|col4|
-------------------+----+----+-------------+----+
27-11-2017 08:20:33|  27|  11|2017 08:20:33|null|
27-11-2017 08:20:35|  27|  11|2017 08:20:35|null|
27-11-2017 08:20:35|  27|  11|2017 08:20:35|null|
```

so, it seems that it doesn't do anything with the space. I have tried using this:

```
.withColumn("col4", split(col("_time"), "\\' '")
```

but that also doesn't work. (gives same result)

any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|` (meaning "or" in Regex) in method `split` to indicate that either `-` or `whitespace` can be the separator, as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  "27-11-2017 08:20:33", "28-12-2017 09:30:44"
).toDF("_time")

df.
  withColumn("tsArr", split($"_time", "\\-|\\s")).
  select($"tsArr"(0), $"tsArr"(1), $"tsArr"(2), $"tsArr"(3)).
  show
// +--------+--------+--------+--------+
// |tsArr[0]|tsArr[1]|tsArr[2]|tsArr[3]|
// +--------+--------+--------+--------+
// |      27|      11|    2017|08:20:33|
// |      28|      12|    2017|09:30:44|
// +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use `date_format`, eg

```
val newDf = df
  .withColumn("_time", unix_timestamp($"_time", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp") )
  .select($"_time", date_format($"_time", "dd"), date_format($"_time", "MM")
    , date_format($"_time", "yyyy"), date_format($"_time", "HH")
    , date_format($"_time", "mm"), date_format($"_time", "ss")
         )

newDf.show
```

More info on `date_format` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_format(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String)) and [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-datetime.html#date_format).